# Aligned multiline equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align

I'm using an `align` environment in a long derivation. Each equality is aligned at the equal sign. Individual lines are too long to fit the page, so I need wrap them. However, I don't just want them to continue in the next line as I usually do and maybe indent them with a `\quad`, I want them to align with the opening bracket which contains all the terms. I've been looking into the `aligned` environment which sort of does what I want, but now the `aligned` lines are vertically centered with the beginning of the equality:

```
\begin{align*}
 Z &= Tr_\text{el, ph}\bigl[\exp(-\beta H)\bigr]\\
 &= \int\mathcal{D}q Tr_\text{el}\biggl[T_\tau\exp\biggl(-\int_0^\beta d\tau\sum_j\Bigl[
 \begin{aligned}
   &-t\sum_\sigma\bigl(c_{j\sigma}^\dag(\tau)c_{j+1,\sigma}(\tau)+\text{h.c.}\bigr)\\
   &+\tfrac{M}{2}\bigl(\dot q_j(\tau)^2+\omega_0^2q_j(\tau)^2\bigr)\\
   &-g\sqrt{2M\omega_0}\sum_\sigma n_{j\sigma}(\tau)q_j(\tau)\Bigr]\biggr)\biggr]
 \end{aligned}\\
 &= ...
\end{align*}
```

[image: What I have]

This is what I would like it to look (photoshopped):
[image]

I imagine, I'm not the first one to have this problem. I did a thorough search before posting this question, so before you mark this as a duplicate, please consider carefully if the alleged duplicate really addresses my issue.

Comment: You are missing the `[t]` option for `aligned`. You might also want to add a `\!` before `\begin{aligned}`

Comment: Very nice, I missed that indeed. Is there maybe a way to center the equation number vertically? It was, before I added `[t]` but now it is on the same height has the equal sign. Maybe that's more reasonable anyway...

Comment: No (AFAIK), the `[t]` changes the baseline, thus I only add it to constructions that are not individually numbered. Yuo could add a single equation number to the entire calculation instead.

Comment: I'll write something a little longer, there are stuff here you should _never_ do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get `aligned` to line up with the first line remember the `[t]` option.

Don't use `\text` for anything but textual comments in display math. This `_\text{el}` is not a textual comment. Better to use another construction.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\Tr{Tr}
% for text only subscripts 
\newcommand\tsub[1]{_\textup{#1}}% or \textnormal
% never use \text for anything but textual comments
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  Z &= \Tr\tsub{el,ph}\bigl[\exp(-\beta H)\bigr]\\
  &= \int\mathcal{D}q
  \Tr\tsub{el}\biggl[T_\tau\exp\biggl(-\int_0^\beta d\tau\sum_j\Bigl[
  \!
 \begin{aligned}[t]
   &-t\sum_\sigma\bigl(c_{j\sigma}^\dag(\tau)c_{j+1,\sigma}(\tau)+\text{h.c.}\bigr)\\
   &+\tfrac{M}{2}\bigl(\dot q_j(\tau)^2+\omega_0^2q_j(\tau)^2\bigr)\\
   &-g\sqrt{2M\omega_0}\sum_\sigma n_{j\sigma}(\tau)q_j(\tau)\Bigr]\biggr)\biggr]
 \end{aligned}\\
 &= ...
\end{align*}

The above waste a bit too much space IMO. Here is another

\begin{align*}
  Z &= \Tr\tsub{el,ph}\bigl[\exp(-\beta H)\bigr]\\
  &= \int\mathcal{D}q
  \Tr\tsub{el}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  \biggl[&T_\tau\exp\biggl(-\int_0^\beta d\tau\sum_j
    \Bigl[
        -t\sum_\sigma\bigl(c_{j\sigma}^\dag(\tau)c_{j+1,\sigma}(\tau)+\text{h.c.}\bigr)
    \\
    &+\tfrac{M}{2}\bigl(\dot q_j(\tau)^2+\omega_0^2q_j(\tau)^2\bigr)
    \sqrt{2M\omega_0}\sum_\sigma
    n_{j\sigma}(\tau)q_j(\tau)\Bigr]\biggr)\biggr]
  \end{aligned}
  \\
  &= ...
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. el and ph are short for "electronic" and "phononic", so I would in fact consider them textual comments. Placing the three additive terms in separate lines make referring to them in the surrounding text easier.

Comment: A different question, but I can't help to notice: you used `\DecaleMathOperator` to define the trace, I usually use `\operatorname`. Is there a reason why one is preferable?

Comment: Less typing. Also `\DeclareMathOperator*` easily makes a `\lim` like operator (where linits go above and below in displayed math)

Comment: As for your comments to `el` and `ph` those are not textual comments, they are textual indices. Big difference. Textual indices should always be upright (just as operator names), but `\text` is italic then the surrounding text is italic!

Comment: Great, the `\lim`-like behavior is actually what I want!